# strong name signing a WP7 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Why is there no strong-name signing support for a WP7 project?   There is no Signing tab in the Project properties.

I've managed to sign it anyways using the AssemblyKeyFile and AssemblyDelaySign attributes in AssemblyInfo.cs, but now I'm wondering if there's a reason why it was removed from the UI?

Comment: is there a GAC in WP7? if not, then it would seem pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WP7, the signing occurs within the Marketplace - not within VS2010. Microsoft apparently get a certificate on your behalf when you signup for the AppHub.

If and when Microsoft provide non-Marketplace "Enterprise" distribution for apps, then they may provide another mechanism for signing.